# From no raid to raid 1 without dataloss

Tags: linux, raid, copy, hard-drive

So im currently using a single 8Tb HDD plugged into my Laptop.

I was thinking about buying an Icybox and another 8Tb HDD and then using the hardware raid 1 of the icybox.

Could that be achieved without dataloss? Or will I have to buy a third HDD, make a copy of the data and then copy the data back to the raid 1?

Comment: Why don't you configure the Icybox to RAID 1 before you put data on it?  If it's possible without data loss will entirely depend on the technical capabilities of the Icybox.  In my experience a product like this isn't configurable through software, I suggest, NOT expecting to be able to switch from RAID 0 to RAID 1.

Comment: Where does the RAID 0 come into the equation? You have a single drive 8TB. You're going to buy a RAID box of some sort. For this to be 8TB RAID 1 it needs 2x8TB drives in it to which you can then copy your existing data. There's no RAID 0 step in this.

Comment: @Tetsujin you're right that was my mistake it's not raid at all, I thought that raid 0 meant no raid, im gonna edit my post

Comment: I think you've pretty much answered your own question now. The RAID 1 needs 2x8TB drives before you can even start. After that it's a straight copy from your old drive to your new RAID. No way round that without 3 drives. You can't build a RAID after the fact.

Comment: Okay, so i guess that it's not possible to achieve this without 3 disks. Thanks for your help @Tetsujin

Comment: Yes, you could build your raid 1 array as *degraded*, with 1 disk missing. Copy your data, then add the 2nd disk to the taid 1 array.

Comment: @r2d3 Keep it friendly.  NLion74 is a new user.  Of course it is ``3.5"``  I assume by plugged in he means in a USB caddy of some sort.  He wants to get one of [these Icy Boxes](https://icybox.de/en/product-list.php?id=1&filterItemCodes%5B%5D=G54-F196&filterItemCodes%5B%5D=G55-F201&filterItemCodes%5B%5D=G57-F207&page=1).  Why the heck would you assume he is moving his laptop system drive to an external enclosure?

Comment: Got it, Blind Spots!

Answer (score 0):

So a few days have passed and though I haven't been able to find anything regarding Icybox's Hardware raid, I've found a way to do it on zfs (I've already been using zfs) but aparently you can just attach a drive to the the existing pool and turn it into a mirror. So im probably going to do that.

Here's the Link if anyone's interested.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/525950/how-to-convert-one-disk-zfs-pool-into-two-disk-raid1-pool